# avoid returning local references (reference to local variable returned - warning)

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have a code snippet that looks as follows. 
I assume this is a bad way to return a pointer since I am returning a local reference. What is good practice, returning `DbTable` copy or pointer `DbTable *`?

```
  DbTable * Catalog::addTable(PartitionScheme  &partScheme, BoundBases &bounds, std::vector<int> &colsPartitioned, const size_t defaultMaxFragmentSize, const TupleDesc &tupleDesc , std::string tableName){

           // some code ...

                    DbTable * dbTable = new DbTable(tableId, basePath, defaultMaxFragmentSize, tupleDesc, partScheme, bounds, colsPartitioned); 
                    cout << "adding dbTable with name: " << tableName << " and table Id " << tableId << endl;
           // some code ...       
                    return dbTable;
            }

    }
```

Comment: just return by value. `DbTable addTable(...);`

Comment: dbTable stores the heap allocated memory. SO it should not have this problem.

Comment: what is the warning you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there is a valid reason not to, prefer to return an object over a pointer allocated on heap.

**Advantages of returning an object**

1. Performance. It takes more time to allocate memory from heap.
2. Less programming errors. You have to deal with memory management issues -- make sure the pointer returned is valid, make sure the allocated memory is deallocated, make sure that the object is not deallocated behind your back leaving you with a dangling pointer, etc.

**When does it make sense to return a pointer?**

1. The sizes of your objects are large. Passing them around and keeping multiple copies would be expensive, both in the memory usage and performance.
2. You have a comprehensive system in place to manage life time of objects -- where they are allocated, who manages them while they are alive, and who manages their deallocation.
3. You have an application in which there is a deep hierarchy of objects and many functions take as input pointers to base classes but rely on the polymorphic behavior of the objects to work correctly.

I suspect there are many other reasons that support both use cases. I just listed a few that jumped out in my mind.

Answer (score -1):

When returning a pointer from a function, if the pointer points to a memory which is locally allocated (not on the heap), it will get deallocated as soon as the function ends. So in that case, it is not a good practice to return the pointer.

In your case, since the memory is allocated on the heap, you can return the pointer.